# How to show $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{r-1}\sin(1/x)$ does not exist for $r\in\mathbb{Q},r<1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm working on a problem that involves showing $\lim_{x\to 0} x^{r-1}\sin(1/x)$ does not exist for $r\in\mathbb{Q},r<1$. I've tried using the Divergence Criterion that states that, given $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$, and $c$ is a cluster point of $A$, $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ does not exist if and only if there exists a sequence $x_n\in A\setminus\{c\}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=c$ and $f(x_n)$ diverges. So then I picked $x_n=(1/n)^{1/(1-r)}$ and determined $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=0.$ Now my next task is showing $f(x_n)=n\sin(n^{1/(1-r)})$ diverges... I'm trying to show $f(x_n)$ is not bounded and am not having any luck, and I can't think of two subsequences that converge to different limits. Any hints for how I should keep going? Should I think of another sequence instead?

Comment: If $r\leq1$, it's as simple as choosing subsequences that are off by $\pi$, for example $$x_n = \frac{2}{\pi(4n+1)}$$ vs $$x_n = \frac{2}{\pi(4n-1)}$$

Comment: If I use those sequences I get $f(x_n)=\left(\frac{\pi(4n+1)}{2}\right)^{1-r}$ or $f(x_n)=-\left(\frac{\pi(4n-1)}{2}\right)^{1-r}$... these clearly both diverge as $n\to\infty$ but I'm not sure how to show that...

Comment: Never mind, I was able to figure it out. Had to show $f(x_n)$ was not Cauchy. Thank you!